# How do you connect to a LocalDB for a new Azure Mobile App?

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-mobile-services

I'm working on converting my Azure Mobile Service to the new Azure Mobile App and want to look at the local database. I've started from a fresh QuickStart project and I can see that my ConnectionString in Web.config is:

```
<add name="MS_TableConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-mobileapp-20160914123002.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-mobileapp-20160914123002;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

However, I don't see the database at all when I look in the (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB server in the SQL Server Object Explorer. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 and I deleted and recreated my connection to my localDB but still no luck. I tried searching for the .mdf file with the same name to see if I could at least add it manually or something but I couldn't find it. Since the project is run on a local IIS server is there a way to see the exact connection string the server is using?

Here's a screenshot of my SQL Server Explorer. The only database I see is AzureStorageEmulatorDb45...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection string is overwritten by Azure App Service with the real connection string that you define.  You can always get the connection string from the code.  It looks like you are using the ASP.NET type of Azure Mobile Apps, so the following code will dump the connection string within a TableController Initialize() method:

```
var connectionString = "MS_TableConnectionString";
var settings = Request.GetConfiguration()
    .GetMobileAppSettingsProvider()
    .GetMobileAppSettings();
ConnectionSettings connectionSettings;
if (!settings.Connections.TryGetValue(connectionString, out connectionSettings))
{
    throw new ArgumentException($"Connection String {connectionString} not found", connectionString);
}
ConnectionString = connectionSettings.ConnectionString;
```

For more information on table controllers, see the chapter in my (in progress) book: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/dataconcepts/

Comment: When testing locally I get the same connection string as the one in my Web.config file as expected. However, when I connect to the database (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB I don't see the database at all. The database's name should be 'aspnet-mobileapp-20160914123002' from the connection string. How do I test the Mobile App database locally?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but I'm now able to see the database. I'm selecting this answer because it answers how to get the connection string and the book is VERY helpful and is a must read.